# multidimensional array in R - getting value

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I have 4-dimentional array in R. I want to get the value from but indexes are hidden in other array.

Example:

```
  >array
  , , SAO2 = HIGH, CCHL = HIGH

           CO
     TPR             HIGH         LOW      NORMAL
     HIGH   0.028571429 0.007968127 0.016806723
     LOW    0.438095238 0.442231076 0.731092437
     NORMAL 0.533333333 0.549800797 0.252100840

, , SAO2 = LOW, CCHL = HIGH

    CO
TPR             HIGH         LOW      NORMAL
  HIGH   0.117860016 0.055415617 0.116427432
  LOW    0.420152856 0.429890848 0.665071770
  NORMAL 0.461987128 0.514693535 0.218500797

> index<-data.frame("1"=c("HIGH","HIGH"),"2"=c("HIGH","HIGH"),"3"=c   ("HIGH","LOW"),"4"=c("HIGH","NORMAL"))
> index

X1   X2   X3     X4
1 HIGH HIGH HIGH   HIGH
2 HIGH HIGH  LOW NORMAL
```

If I try this command:

```
    array[index[1,]]
```

I got an error:

```
    Error in `[.default`(array, index[1, ]) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I understand the reason but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Try converting to `matrix` or do `unlist` i.e. `array[as.matrix[index[1,])]`

Comment: Without having your data, it's hard to test, but try `cbind` instead of `data.frame`. `cbind(c("HIGH","HIGH"),c("HIGH","HIGH"),c("HIGH","LOW"),c("HIGH","NORMAL"))`

Comment: The `matrix` option should work `array <- xtabs(mpg + disp ~ cyl + vs + am + gear, mtcars);
   index1 <- data.frame(X1 = c("4", "6"), X2 = c("0", "1"), X3 = c("0", "1"), c("5", "5"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);array[as.matrix(index1[1,])]#
[1] 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the `data.frame` to `matrix` and it should work

```
array[as.matrix[index[1,])]
```